# Gradle DSL method not found: 'gbuildscript()' using /gradle-play-publisher

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, google-play-developer-api

I am trying to use a [Gradle plugin](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher) to upload an APK + Google Play details following a [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Automating-Publishing-to-the-Play-Store) but I have an error syncing Gradle:

> Error:(1, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'gbuildscript()'

I follow the tutorial steps defining and using the dependencies in build.gradle of the application, and build with 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'. I have found people asking for similar questions for methods not found like proguard or compile but their solutions are already used or do not apply for my case. Have you deal with a similar problem?

Comment: I think you've missplet 'buildscript' as 'gbuildscript' in your build.gradle

Comment: Indeed. I was looking in some other places but not there. Thanks!